# Difference between vcard and vcard_search table in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

What is difference between vcard and vcard_search table in ejabberd.I mean to say for what purpose they are used?

Answer (score 1):

vcard table is used to store the raw vCard. vcard_search is an index table, used for searching user vCard by field. It is for example use in user directory queries to find the list of matching users.

You can read more details about each field here: http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/sql-schema/